# Python PLY parsing nested matching parentheses

Tags: python, parsing, ply

I'm parsing with [PLY](https://github.com/dabeaz/ply). I want a token for the largest group of matching parenthesis that contains nested matching parenthesis within it.

For example:

1. `a(b|c(d|e))` should match everything after 'a'
2. `a(b)(c)(d)` shouldn't match

With the `regex` module this might be possible with something like:
`\([^()]*\(((?>[^()]+|(?R))*)\)[^()]*\)`

But I believe PLY is using `re` which doesn't have recursion. Is there some other way I can accomplish this without having to manually parse out the token myself in my `p_` (parsing) functions?

Comment: Yep, a parser bis what's called for, here

Comment: Well I'm already writing a parser. I wanted this for one of the tokens and in PLY I don't see a way to generate tokens other than regex. Is there another python parser that supports more dynamic tokens?

Comment: You can write your own lexer and plug it into PLY; the manual explains how to do that. It's pretty straightforward.

Comment: `pyparsing` has a `nestedExpr`.